# What are the benefits of using a custom enumeration like Direction over built-in types like System.Byte or String?

Tags: c#, asp.net

What are the benefits of using a custom enumeration like Direction over built-in types like System.Byte or String?

This question is asked in Mumbai University for "B.Sc.IT" (ASP.NET With C#) Course in the year - may/2018. I'm not gettin' correct answer. Please help me anyone, who the know the correct answers for this question.

Comment: An `enum` is nothing like `string` or `byte`, why compare them?

Comment: Please add to your question what you have done to solve this exercise. This enables us to see what may be missing. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I think what this question is getting at is that an enumeration has a predefined set of values, so things like typos are caught by the compiler. For example:

```
public enum Direction{
Up, Down, Left, Right
}
```

It's impossible to define a `Direction` as `Diagonal`, the compiler won't let you. You also get [intelli sense](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-intellisense?view=vs-2017) from enums:

[image]

Strings/Bytes do not have a well defined list of values. This is summed up nicely by the meme [stringly typing](http://wiki.c2.com/?StringlyTyped):

> Method parameters that take strings when other more appropriate types
>   should be used. On the occasion that a string is required in a method
>   call (e.g. network service), the string is then passed and used
>   throughout the rest of the call graph without first converting it to a
>   more suitable internal representation (e.g. parse it and create an
>   enum, then you have strong typing throughout the rest of your
>   codebase). Message passing without using typed messages etc.
>   Excessively stringly typed code is usually a pain to understand and
>   **detonates at runtime with errors that the compiler would normally
>   find**.

Answer (score -1):

So you don't end up with data like

- N
- n
- North
- Nor.
- N.
- Nord

When you were expecting a compass direction. Using a string instead of an Enum or at least a constraint of some sort will make queries and reports a huge annoyance for everybody that comes after you, forever.

Comment: The data type you use to store the information in your code has basically nothing to do with what the UI control is for the user to input that data.  You don't need to use an Enum to limit the valid values a user can provide to a fixed set of values.

Comment: @Servy That assumes that nobody will ever input data except through the UI. Data can come from anywhere and there is no guarantee that it will be properly sanitized or even valid. If an Enum is used the data will either be valid or missing.

Comment: You can most certainly provide invalid values for an enum.  If you have other means of inputting data into the system, then they also need to ensure that any data inputted is valid.  That is true *regardless* of what data type you use to store the data in your code, and likewise can be accomplished with basically any data type you use to store your data.